# How to tell ansible to use a key

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm not very familiar with ansible. 
The problem I have at the moment is the following:
I have a master - nodes environment with multiple nodes.
My ansible needs to access my nodes but can't access them.

```
SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I'm able to SSH from my master to each node but only by using a key:

```
ssh -i key-to-node.pem centos@ec2...
```

Is it possible to setup something to allow ansible to connect to the created hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your pem file in your [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file):

```
private_key_file=key-to-node.pem
```

If you don't have one, create one at the same location where you playbook is or in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

If you have different keys for your hosts, you can also define the key in your [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters):

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=key-to-node.pem
```

Also, if you would have configured ssh to work without explicitly passing the private key file (in your `.ssh/config`) Ansible would automatically work.

---

Adding an example from the OpenShift page, as mentioned in the comments.

I personally have never configured it this way (as I have set up everything via `~/.ssh/config` but according to the docs it should be working like this:

```
[masters]
master.example.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=1.pem

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
node1.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}" ansible_ssh_private_key_file=2.pem
```

Alternatively, since you have multiple nodes and maybe the same key for all of them, you can define a separate `nodes:vars` section

```
[nodes:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=2.pem
```

Comment: thanks, had to change remote_user too to make my login possible (was not in question)

Comment: My inventory file looks like "Example 1. Single Master and Multiple Nodes Inventory File" on  https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/advanced_install.html. How can I use 2 keys over there. One for my master and one key for my nodes?

Comment: I added an example above.

Comment: So I can just add [nodes:vars] and [master:vars] at the end of the inventory with their key?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I just found your other question and answered there with an example.

Comment: Alternatively you can also pass --private-key <private key location> on the command line when executing ansible-playbook.